# How to print range values with specific reference number are given?

Tags: perl, match, lines

I have a set of data file looks like below. I would like to get the interpolation final value (final,P) by referring to 2 set of number range (scoreA and scoreB). Let's say for "Eric", his scoreA is 35 (value between range 30.00 - 40.00) and scoreB is 48 (a value between range 45.00 - 50.00). He will get 2 set of final values range which are (22.88,40.90) & (26.99,38.99).  And I would like to get the final value of "Eric" and "George" in the data file. "George"'s scoreA = 38 and scoreB = 26.

After formula calculation, I want to get the exact final value when his scoreA=35 & scoreB=45. Let's assume formula is P=X+Y (P is final value), so far I have been trying the code as shown below. However it cannot get the correct lines.

How to get the exactly final value range by referring to the data given?

**data file**

```
Student_name ("Eric")   
/* This is a junk line */   
scoreA ("10.00, 20.00, 30.00, 40.00")  
scoreB ("15.00, 30.00, 45.00, 50.00, 55.00")     
final (  
"12.23,19.00,37.88,45.98,60.00",\  
"07.00,20.11,24.56,45.66,57.88",\  
"05.00,15.78,22.88,40.90,57.99",\  
"10.00,16.87,26.99,38.99,40.66"\)  

Student_name ("Liy") 
/* This is a junk line */   
scoreA ("5.00, 10.00, 20.00, 60.00")  
scoreB ("25.00, 30.00, 40.00, 55.00, 60.00")     
final (  
"02.23,15.00,37.88,45.98,70.00",\  
"10.00,28.11,34.56,45.66,57.88",\  
"08.00,19.78,32.88,40.90,57.66",\  
"10.00,27.87,39.99,59.99,78.66"\)

Student_name ("Frank") 
/* This is a junk line */   
scoreA ("2.00, 15.00, 25.00, 40.00")  
scoreB ("15.00, 24.00, 38.00, 45.00, 80.00")     
final (  
"02.23,15.00,37.88,45.98,70.00",\  
"10.00,28.11,34.56,45.66,57.88",\  
"08.00,19.78,32.88,40.90,57.66",\  
"10.00,27.87,39.99,59.99,78.66"\)

Student_name ("George") 
/* This is a junk line */   
scoreA ("10.00, 15.00, 20.00, 40.00")  
scoreB ("25.00, 33.00, 46.00, 55.00, 60.00")     
final (  
"10.23,25.00,37.88,45.98,68.00",\  
"09.00,28.11,34.56,45.66,60.88",\  
"18.00,19.78,32.88,40.90,79.66",\  
"17.00,27.87,40.99,59.99,66.66"\)
```

**Coding**

```
data();      
sub data() {   
    my $cnt = 0;
    while (my @array = <FILE>) {
        foreach $line(@array) {    
            if ($line =~ /Student_name/) {
                $a = $line;

                if ($a =~ /Eric/ or $cnt > 0 ) {
                    $cnt++;
                }
                if ( $cnt > 1 and $cnt <= 3 ) {
                    print $a;
                }
                if ( $cnt > 2 and $cnt <= 4 ) {
                    print $a;
                }
                if ( $cnt == 5 ) {
                    $cnt  =  0;  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
Eric    final=42.66  
George  final=24.30
```

Comment: There are two seperate problems here: (1) how to parse the file, and (2) how to calculate the scores. Parsing is fairly easy, but I don't understand how you calculate the scores: What data points are you using? Can you clarify the algorithm? Can you explain your terminology?

Comment: Please explain 1) Where the values for scoreA and scoreB for each person come from? 2) What meaning the `final` values have in the data file? 3) What meaning the two pairs of final values has? 4) What relation the final value `P` has to the four "final values"

Comment: @amon-This is a simple example similar to my file. Actually I use bilinear interpolation equation for calculation.

Comment: [google](http://www.ajdesigner.com/phpinterpolation/bilinear_interpolation_equation.php)

Comment: @Borodin-Those example numbers are random generated by computer, I would like to find out the exact final value after bilinear interpolation calculation if his score fall in between the range. For an example "Eric", 
note: * is computer generated formula and calculation.  
scoreA (x0, x1, x2, x3)  
scoreB (y0, y1, y2, y3, y4)  
each final value obtained: first row(x0*y0),(x0*y1),(x0*y2),(x0*y3),(x0*y4)//second row
(x1*y0),(x1*y1),(x1*y2)...

Comment: I added a few notes about implementing bilinear interpolation to my answer. However, I don't understand the meaning of your last comment, and why you suddenly talk about *single* values for `scoreA` and `scoreB` in the first paragraph of your question when they are lists.

Answer (score 1):

In my comment I said that parsing is *fairly* easy. Here is how it could be done. As the question lacks a proper specification of the file format, I will assume the following:

The file consists of *properties*, which have *values*:

```
document ::= property*
property ::= word "(" value ("," value)* ")"
```

A value is a double-quoted string containing numbers seperated by commata, or a single word:

```
value ::= '"' ( word | number ("," number)* ) '"'
```

Spaces, backslashes, and comments are irrelevant.

Here is a possible implementation; I will not go into the details of explaining how to write a simple parser.

```
package Parser;
use strict; use warnings;

sub parse {
  my ($data) = @_;

  # perform tokenization

  pos($data) = 0;
  my $length = length $data;
  my @tokens;
  while(pos($data) < $length) {
    next if $data =~ m{\G\s+}gc
         or $data =~ m{\G\\}gc
         or $data =~ m{\G/[*].*?[*]/}gc;
    if ($data =~ m/\G([",()])/gc) {
      push @tokens, [symbol => $1];
    } elsif ($data =~ m/\G([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)/gc) {
      push @tokens, [number => 0+$1];
    } elsif ($data =~ m/\G(\w+)/gc) {
      push @tokens, [word => $1];
    } else {
      die "unreckognized token at:\n", substr $data, pos($data), 10;
    }
  }

  return parse_document(\@tokens);
}

sub token_error {
  my ($token, $expected) = @_;
  return "Wrong token [@$token] when expecting [@$expected]";
}

sub parse_document {
  my ($tokens) = @_;
  my @properties;
  push @properties, parse_property($tokens) while @$tokens;
  return @properties;
}

sub parse_property {
  my ($tokens) = @_;
  $tokens->[0][0] eq "word"
    or die token_error $tokens->[0], ["word"];
  my $name = (shift @$tokens)->[1];
  $tokens->[0][0] eq "symbol" and $tokens->[0][1] eq '('
    or die token_error $tokens->[0], [symbol => '('];
  shift @$tokens;
  my @vals;
  VAL: {
    push @vals, parse_value($tokens);
    if ($tokens->[0][0] eq 'symbol' and $tokens->[0][1] eq ',') {
      shift @$tokens;
      redo VAL;
    }
  }
  $tokens->[0][0] eq "symbol" and $tokens->[0][1] eq ')'
    or die token_error $tokens->[0], [symbol => ')'];
  shift @$tokens;
  return [ $name => @vals ];
}

sub parse_value {
  my ($tokens) = @_;
  $tokens->[0][0] eq "symbol" and $tokens->[0][1] eq '"'
    or die token_error $tokens->[0], [symbol => '"'];
  shift @$tokens;

  my $value;

  if ($tokens->[0][0] eq "word") {
    $value = (shift @$tokens)->[1];
  } else {
    my @nums;
    NUM: {
      $tokens->[0][0] eq 'number'
        or die token_error $tokens->[0], ['number'];
      push @nums, (shift @$tokens)->[1];
      if ($tokens->[0][0] eq 'symbol' and $tokens->[0][1] eq ',') {
        shift @$tokens;
        redo NUM;
      }
    }
    $value = \@nums;
  }

  $tokens->[0][0] eq "symbol" and $tokens->[0][1] eq '"'
    or die token_error $tokens->[0], [symbol => '"'];
  shift @$tokens;

  return $value;
}
```

Now, we get the following data structure as output from `Parser::parse`:

```
(
  ["Student_name", "Eric"],
  ["scoreA", [10, 20, 30, 40]],
  ["scoreB", [15, 30, 45, 50, 55]],
  [
    "final",
    [12.23, 19, 37.88, 45.98, 60],
    [7, 20.11, 24.56, 45.66, 57.88],
    [5, 15.78, 22.88, 40.9, 57.99],
    [10, 16.87, 26.99, 38.99, 40.66],
  ],
  ["Student_name", "Liy"],
  ["scoreA", [5, 10, 20, 60]],
  ["scoreB", [25, 30, 40, 55, 60]],
  [
    "final",
    [2.23, 15, 37.88, 45.98, 70],
    [10, 28.11, 34.56, 45.66, 57.88],
    [8, 19.78, 32.88, 40.9, 57.66],
    [10, 27.87, 39.99, 59.99, 78.66],
  ],
  ...,
)
```

As a next step, we want to transform it into nested hashes, so that we have the structure

```
{
  Eric => {
    scoreA => [...],
    scoreB => [...],
    final  => [[...], ...],
  },
  Liy => {...},
  ...,
}
```

So we simply run it through this small sub:

```
sub properties_to_hash {
  my %hash;
  while(my $name_prop = shift @_) {
    $name_prop->[0] eq 'Student_name' or die "Expected Student_name property";
    my $name = $name_prop->[1];
    while( @_ and $_[0][0] ne 'Student_name') {
      my ($prop, @vals) = @{ shift @_ };
      if (@vals > 1) {
        $hash{$name}{$prop} = \@vals;
      } else {
        $hash{$name}{$prop} = $vals[0];
      }
    }
  }
  return \%hash;
}
```

So we have the main code

```
my $data = properties_to_hash(Parser::parse( $file_contents ));
```

*Now* we can move on to Part 2 fo the problem: calculating your scores. That is, once you make clear what you need done.

#### Edit: Bilinear interpolation

Let *f* be the function that returns the value at a certain coordinate. If we have a value at those coordinates, we can return that. Else, we perform bilinear interpolation with the next known values.

The **formula for bilinear interpolation**<sup>[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation#Algorithm)]</sup> is:

```
f(x, y) = 1/( (x_2 - x_1) · (y_2 - y_1) ) · (
              f(x_1, y_1) · (x_2 - x) · (y_2 - y)
            + f(x_2, y_1) · (x - x_1) · (y_2 - y)
            + f(x_1, y_2) · (x_2 - x) · (y - y_1)
            + f(x_2, y_2) · (x - x_1) · (y - y_1)
          )
```

Now, `scoreA` denote the positions of the data points in the `final` table on the first axis, `scoreA` the positions on the second axis. We have to do the following:

1. assert that the requested values `x, y` are inside the bounds
2. fetch the next smaller and next larger positions
3. perform interpolation

.

```
sub f {
   my ($data, $x, $y) = @_;

   # do bounds check:
   my ($x_min, $x_max, $y_min, $y_max) = (@{$data->{scoreA}}[0, -1], @{$data->{scoreB}}[0, -1]);
   die "indices ($x, $y) out of range ([$x_min, $x_max], [$y_min, $y_max])"
      unless $x_min <= $x && $x <= $x_max
          && $y_min <= $y && $y <= $y_max;
```

To fetch the boxing indices `x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2` we need to iterate through all possible scores. We'll also remember the physical indices `x_i1, x_i2, y_i1, y_i2` of the underlying arrays.

```
   my ($x_i1, $x_i2, $y_i1, $y_i2);
   for ([$data->{scoreA}, \$x_i1, \$x_i2], [$data->{scoreB}, \$y_i1, \$y_i2]) {
      my ($scores, $a_i1, $a_i2) = @$_;
      for my $i (0 .. $#$scores) {
         if ($scores->[$i] <= $x) {
            ($$a_i1, $$a_i2) = $i == $#$scores ? ($i, $i+1) : ($i-1, $i);
            last;
         }
      }
   }
   my ($x_1, $x_2) = @{$data->{scoreA}}[$x_i1, $x_i2];
   my ($y_1, $y_2) = @{$data->{scoreB}}[$y_i1, $y_i2];
```

Now, interpolation according to above formula can be performed, but each access at a known index can be changed to an access via physical index, so `f(x_1, y_2)` would become

```
$final->[$x_i1][$y_i2]
```

---

#### Detailed Explanation of `sub f`

- `sub f { ... }` declares a sub with name `f`, although that is probably a bad name. `bilinear_interpolation` might be a better name.
- `my ($data, $x, $y) = @_` states that our sub takes three arguments:

  1. `$data`, a hash reference containing fields `scoreA`, `scoreB` and `final`, which are array references.
  2. `$x`, the position along the `scoreA`-axis where interpolation is required.
  3. `$y`, the position along the `scoreB`-axis where interpolation is required.
- Next, we want to assert that the positions for `$x` and `$y` are valid aka inside bounds. The first value in `$data->{scoreA}` is the minimal value; the maximal value is in the last position (index `-1`). To get both at once, we use an *array slice*. A slice accesses multiple values at once and returns a list, like `@array[1, 2]`. Because we use complex data structures which use references, we have to dereference the array in `$data->{scoreA}`. This makes the slice look like `@{$data->{scoreA}}[0, 1]`.

  Now that we have the `$x_min` and `$x_max` values, we throw and error unless the requested value `$x` is inside the range defined by the min/max values. This is true when

  ```
  $x_min <= $x && $x <= $x_max
  ```

  Should either `$x` or `$y` be out of bounds, we throw an error which shows the actual bounds. So the code

  ```
  die "indices ($x, $y) out of range ([$x_min, $x_max], [$y_min, $y_max])"
  ```

  could, for example, throw an error like

  ```
  indices (10, 500) out of range ([20, 30], [25, 57]) at script.pl line 42
  ```

  Here we can see that the value for `$x` is too small, and `$y` is too large.
- The next problem is to find neighbouring values. Assuming `scoreA` holds `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and `$x` is `3.7`, we want to select the values `3` and `4`. But because we can pull some nifty tricks a bit later, we would rather remember the *position* of the neighbouring values, not the values themselves. So this would give `2` and `3` in above example (remember that arrows are zero-based).

  We can do this by looping over all indices of our array. When we find a value that is ≤ `$x`, we remember the index. E.g. `3` is the first value that is ≤ `$x`, so we remember the index `2`. For the next higher value, we have to be a bit carful: Obviously, we can just take the next index, so `2 + 1 = 3`. But now assume that `$x` is `5`. This passes the bounds check. The first value that is ≤ `$x` would be value `5`, so we can remember position `4`. However, there is no entry at position `5`, so we could use the current index itself. Because this would lead to division by zero later on, we would be better off remembering positions `3` and `4` (values `4` and `5`).

  Expressed as code, that is

  ```
  my ($x_i1, $x_i2);
  my @scoreA = @{ $data->{scoreA} }; # shortcut to the scoreA entry
  for my $i (0 .. $#scores) {        # iterate over all indices: `$#arr` is the last idx of @arr
     if ($scores[$i] <= $x) {        # do this if the current value is ≤ $x
        if ($i != $#scores) {        # if this isn't the last index
           ($x_i1, $x_i2) = ($i, $i+1);
        } else {                     # so this is the last index
           ($x_i1, $x_i2) = ($i-1, $i);
        }
        last;                        # break out of the loop
     }
  }
  ```

  In my original code I choose a more complex solution to avoid copy-pasting the same code for finding the neighbours of `$y`.

  Because we also need the values, we obtain them via a slice with the indices:

  ```
  my ($x_1, $x_2) = @{$data->{scoreA}}[$x_i1, $x_i2];
  ```
- Now we have all surrounding values `$x1, $x_2, $y_1, $y_2` which define the rectangle in which we want to perform bilinear interpolation. The mathematical formula is easy to translate to Perl: just choose the correct operators (`*`, not `·` for multiplication), and the variables need dollar signs before them.

  The formula I used is *recursive*: The definition of *f* refers to itself. This would imply an infinite loop, unless we do some thinking and break the recursion. *f* symbolizes the value at a certain position. In most cases, this means interpolating. However, if `$x` and `$y` are both equal to values in `scoreA` and `scoreB` respectively, we don't need bilinear interpolation, and can return the `final` entry directly.

  This can be done by checking if both `$x` and `$y` are members of their arrays, and doing an early return. Or we can use the fact that `$x_1, ..., $y_2` all are members of the arrays. Instead of recursing with values we *know* don't need interpolating, we just do an array access. This is what we have saved the indices `$x_i1, ..., $y_i2` for. So wherever the original formula says `f(x_1, y_1)` or similar, we write the equivalent `$data->{final}[$x_i1][$y_i2]`.

Comment: @amon-thanks for your guidance. I have questions about coding. 1) The main code: my $data = properties_to_hash(Parser::parse( $file_contents )); what is $file_contents?  2) what if I want only Eric and George' final values to be shown?

Comment: there are errors like: Bareword found where operator expected at  line 53, near "document ::"
        (Do you need to predeclare document?)
Bareword found where operator expected at line 54, near "property ::"
        (Do you need to predeclare property?)String found where operator expected at Dvalue.pl line 55, near ") '"'"
        (Missing operator before '"'?)
syntax error at line 53, near "document ::"
Can't use global @_ in "my" at line 58, near "= @_"
syntax error at line 81, near "}" // I don't understand how to use parser and declaration

Comment: (1) The `$file_contents` are the contents of the file you want to parse. E.g. `use File::Slurp; my $file_contents = read_file("data.file");`. (2) Once you have fully parsed the file into a hash, you can delete any entries you are not interested in, e.g. `/^(?:Eric|George)$/ or delete $data->{$_} for keys %$data`. (3) I dont know where your errors come from, my code worked for me. The parser can be put in a file `Parser.pm` in the same dir as your script. Then `use Parser` to load the code.

Comment: Ah, now I see your problem: my first two code sections are *not* Perl code, but [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF) notation for the grammar (the structure) of your file format, which is used to describe Parsers.

Comment: @amon- meaning, document ::= property*;
#property ::= word "(" value ("," value)* ")";
are not perl code right. How do the coding handle input from my database file by using parser?

Comment: You load the file into a string, e.g. via `File::Slurp`. The `Parser::parse` function then operates on that string. I won't write out the whole code for you, I already covered all the difficult parts. What is left for you to do really isn't hard, provided that you have minimal experience with programming, and a basic grasp of Perl.

Comment: @amon- Perhaps my perl version cannot locate parser.pm. After compilation, it shows: can't locate File/Slurp.pm in my perl version pakage. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your guidance and help =D Very much appreciate.

Comment: `File::Slurp` is not a core module, but can be installed from CPAN. Equivalently, you can do `my $file_contents = do { open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!"; local $/; <$fh>};`

Comment: @amon- I wrote this to find specific name after interpolation. sub name {

if ($name =~ /^(?:Eric|George)$/) {
print "[$x_i1][$y_i2]\n";
}

} is this fine? It seems wrong in somewhere. I have another question. In interpolation function, I have fixed scoreA and scoreB as reference numbers to get the nearest range. in sub f { my $a = 38;
my $b = 26;

if ( $x_min < $a < $x_max) {
@{$data->{scoreA}}[0, -1];
}

if ( $y_min < $b < $y_max) {
@{$data->{scoreB}}[0, -1];
} } Is this the way to find the correct range? Can you explain what does [0, -1] means? Thanks...

Comment: I added a detailed explanation of my half-implementation for bilinear interpolation which explains some shortcuts, and the general algorithm. Note: in Perl, you have to write `$x < $y < $z` as `$x < $y && $y < $z`.